# MySQLi Equivalent Of MySQL Code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can you give me the equivalent of this code im MySQLi? Can't get it right.

```
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid'"))){
//code to be exectued if user exists
} 
?>
```

**EDIT:** Care to explain to me what is wrong?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $pass, $db);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('The Server Is Busy. Please Try Again Later.');
}
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid'");
if ($result->num_rows) {
    echo "<h1>AWESOME</h1>";
}
```

Comment: You can do with one extra query select FOUND_ROWS()

Comment: Yeah. You can also drink your milk through your nose!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, in an OO sense, it would go from:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid'"))){
    //code to be exectued if user exists
}
```

To (assuming numeric userid):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = ".(int) $userid);
if ($result->num_rows) {
    //code
}
```

To (assuming string userid) :

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = '". $db->real_escape_string($userid) . "');
if ($result->num_rows) {
    //code
}
```

To (assuming prepared statements) :

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows) {
    //code
}
```

Now, that's assuming you're using the OOP version of MySQLi (which you should be, IMHO, since it makes life easier in a lot of ways).

Comment: Oh return of the colonel. Missed ya.

Comment: @Col: Updated.  Good point, I just assumed it was an int (stupid, I know)

Comment: I'd leave prepared statements example only

Comment: @ircmaxell-Thanks! @Colonel-Thanks!

Comment: @WideBlade: And your problem was?

Comment: @mchl - not sure. i think the (int) part.

Comment: but it was something in the configurations, which means you were right.

Comment: Well, then check what is in fact in `$userid` variable. Do `var_dump('$userid');`, just to be sure it actually contains user's id.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row['userid'] > 0 ) {
  echo "<h1>AWESOME</h1>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(...);

if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid'"))){
//code to be exectued if user exists
}
```

---

Way I'd do it:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(...);

$result = mysqli_query(
  $connection,
  "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid'"
) or die(mysqli_error());  //use proper error handling here: or die() used for brevity

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['cnt'] > 0) {
  //do your thing
}
```

Comment: No GO My Friend. Tried it before asking :)

Comment: @WideBlade: Then why you not stated in the question?

Comment: Then there must be something else wrong, but you show us too little information. Do you get any error messages? Is $connection actually a mysqli link resource?

Comment: Indeed it is. Can you show me a different way to find if a user exists in db?

Comment: This is correct way. You're just doing something wrong, and don't want us to help you.

Comment: @Mchl - I am indeed known for being lazy.

Comment: My bet is, that your query is failing for some reason. Maybe `$userid` is empty? Try echoing `$mysqli->error`

Comment: @Mchl despite of the OP's dusgusting attitude, your answer is wrong. It lacks the reason, why one should use mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Your comment lacks reason at all. The reason for using mysqli instead of mysql is that the OP wants to use mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - because one gets some free storage space and would like to use it instead of buying storage space.