# mysqli num_rows nested query

Tags: php, mysqli, nested

I'm updating a site from MySQL to MySQLi, using OOP.

For the most part things are going well, but this line is giving me divine trouble:

```
$pager_total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($MySQLctr,$MyDB));
```

I've tried

```
$pager_total = $MyDB->query($MySQLctr)->num_rows;
and
$pager_total = ($MyDB->query($MySQLctr))->num_rows;
and
$new_object = $MyDB->query($MySQLctr);
$pager_total = $new_object->num_rows;
```

but no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that `$MyDB->query($MySQLctr)` is returning a [mysqli-result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object? What happens when you `var_dump` it?

Comment: don't nest/chain DB calls. that assumes that nothing could ever possibly go wrong, which is exactly the wrong thing to do. never assume success. always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Enable error display and add this to the top of your script to see what - if any - errors you get: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 0):

OOP mysqli is very simple :) try this example

```
$DBH=new mysql('location of database','username','password','database');
$get=$DBH->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table');//notice the count(*) in the query, it's not the same as mysql_num_row() but works in the same way
//prepare is also a more secure way of processing query, please look up the difference between prepare and query though.
//$DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=2'); will not work.
$get->execute();//execute the above prepared statement
$get->bind_result($count);//get the result of the query, should be whatever COUNT(*) returns
$get->close();//don't forget to close your connection
```

The mysqli of `mysql_num_row()` is `$query->num_rows()`.

I added a little bit extra to get you started with OOP mysqli :) 
Notice though that I didn't use `$get->num_rows()` but `COUNT(*)` instead for a more simple example. Here is another method you may be more familiar with:

```
$counter=$DBH->query('SELECT * FROM table');
echo$counter->num_rows();
```

Also see [here for more examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874699/mysqli-equivalent-of-mysql-code)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everyone. It turns out that the db connection was being closed prematurely by one of the included files. I've noticed, during this project where I'm transitioning the code from procedural MySql to OOP MySQLi that the db closures didn't affect the functionality of the site before, but definitely do once OOP MySqli is in place. I'm curious why.